# No such file or directory - Magento Error

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I am getting the error below:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:48:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory";i:1;s:2322:"#0 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(300): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
#8 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('read')
#9 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#10 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(449): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#11 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#12 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1175): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#13 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#14 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#15 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(408): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#16 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(338): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#17 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/blahblahblah/public_html/index.php(128): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I have checked that `/home/blahblahblah/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` exists and the permissions to all directories leading up to it are 755 with the file being set at 644.

I have done everything I can think of maybe someone else has a clue on what else would cause this?

I also forgot to mention that file ownership belongs to the correct user also. I used rSync to move the entire directory over to a new server. The installation on the server I pulled it from is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you try to connect to mysql via a socket and that fails. Is Mysql running right and is your configuration right.

The error is coming from the file you did mention, so that isn't the problem, Magento does see that file.

**Solution**

Try using an IP to connect to Mysql. Or check if your mysql-socket is right.

Comment: WOW I am an idiot! I forgot to change the database connection string in local.xml. What gave you the clue that it was trying to connect via a socket?

Comment: Had the same problem once, oops. :) Feel free to take it as an answer.